# Does Jetpack Joyride end?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I've noticed increasing sectors numbers in the background of Jetpack Joyride.

Do these sectors ever end? Can you escape with the jet pack?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is an end. 30000 meters and a wall zaps you, and that's the end.

Comment: Huh, I would have imagined it would just be all randomly generated

Comment: That is pretty anti-climactic.

Comment: so Bad End ? maybe there was other requirement to get Good Ending :v

Answer (score 6):

The highest score appears to be 30,000m. I'd imagine that's the end.

Comment: That's thirty-thousand million, or thirty billion, right?

Comment: @Zsub 30,000 meters.

Comment: @Zsub M is for mega- (millions), m is milli (thousandths)

Comment: @NickT Hehe, true, true.

Comment: What the hell? Guys, the game measures the distance you travel in meters and represents it with an 'm'. We really don't need a deep and meaningful over what kind of m it is.

Comment: Yeah but how many levels are there? I'm level 185 and don't see any end in the near future...

Comment: Adam, if you have your own question, feel free to ask it. Maybe someone knows the answer...