# Is it possible to pass the 30,000 Meters in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Jetpack Joyride end?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43283/does-jetpack-joyride-end)

My friends tell me you have to have a Vehicle Equipped but I've tried it more than twenty times and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What your friends are telling you is bogus.  30,000 meters is the max distance in Jetpack Joyride, and in the end, a wall zaps you, "killing" you.